# git jenkins scm plugin Permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, ssh-agent

When I try to set up a job to build a project from a git repository I get an error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@ssh://git@host.com/path/to/repos.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

In Jenkins, I installed the SSH Agent plugin and the Git plugin.

I can add a build step with the following:

```
git ls-remote -h ssh://git@host.com/path/to/repos.git HEAD
```

Run the build and that works!

This tells me that everything is setup properly:

- Keys and location of the keys.
- Jenkins/Manage Jenkins/Manage Plugins -> SSH agent plugin and Git Plugin.
- Jenkins/Manage Jenkins/Manage Credentials entry is correct.

It seem this doesn't work for Source Code Management, but for pre-build/build/post-build operation it does.

Is there a problem with the Ssh agent not being activated before the build process?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a problem with the SSH agent not being activated before the build process?" - Yes, and it's annoying.

I did read 'somewhere' in my hunting that they are planning to make the SSH agent wrap around git and other plugins correctly in the future.

If you run a simple shell command with the SSH Agent setup you will clearly see it start and stop before and after the shell command in the console output for the build, this does not happen when git details have been entered.

Just continue to use the build steps as described for now...